# Regular expression validation error

Tags: angularjs, regex

I'm using regex for validating numbers in angularjs. But my code shows validation error when the number exceeds 9 digits.Could someone please help me to rectify my code such that any digits of number can be entered.

What I have tried is :

```
ng-pattern="/^\d{0,9}?$/"
```

Comment: `\d{0,9}?` why using `?` here

Comment: @Tushar because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38790314/256196)?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the {0,9}? and use * instead like

```
/^\d*$/
```

{0,9} mean is any length between 0 and 9

Comment: can you tell me what should i add if i need to validate decimals too. What i tried before was like ng-pattern="/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,9})?$/"

Comment: @anju Here : "/^[\d]*[\.]?[\d]*$/"

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is understanding the difference between:

- `{0,9}`
- `[0-9]`

`{0,9}` means "zero to 9 repetitions of the preceding term", which in this case means "zero to 9 digits".

`[0-9]` means "a character in the range 0 to 9 (inclusive)", which is the same as `\d`.

Try:

```
/^\d+$/
```

Which means "all numeric input" and excludes blank input.

To allow decimal input too, escape the dot and make the decimal part optional:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Which means "at least one digit, optionally followed by a dot and at least one digit".

Comment: Thank you for your help.What should i add if i need to validate decimals too. What i tried before was like ng-pattern="/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,9})?$/"

Comment: @anju is blank input allowed too?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `{0,9}` quantifier with the `*`. And remove the `?` -- it's useless:

```
ng-pattern="/^\d*$/"
```

For decimal values:

```
ng-pattern="/^\d*(\.\d+)?$/"
```

Comment: can you tell me what should i add if i need to validate decimals too. What i tried before was like ng-pattern="/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,9})?$/"

Comment: I believe open quantifiers are just fine in your case: `$\d*(\.\d+)?$`. These result in a simple regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
  "/^\d*?$/"
```

`\d{0,9}`  = match 0 to 9 digits

`\d*` = match 0 to N digits

\d = digit : 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9

Comment: can you tell me what should i add if i need to validate decimals too. What i tried before was like ng-pattern="/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,9})?$/"

Comment: You don't need `?` when using `*` quantifier